# Why doesn't this html code work?

Tags: php, html, variables

Given the following `index.html` file:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Welcome to <?= $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see "Welcome to EXAMPLE.COM", All I see is "Welcome to ".
What would cause this to happen if the code checks out?

Comment: Not enough info... where have you put the code? what have you called the file? is it actually running the PHP? etc...

Comment: it's just an index.html file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not running because that part is not html (it's php) but you have saved it as an html file instead of as a php file.

rename it to index.php and try again?

Comment: Awesome, that totally worked... derp. Thank you very much! Is there an html version of that part in question so i can keep it a ".html" extension?

Comment: Nah, html doesn't do anything dynamic like that. If you want dynamic stuff - it needs to be php.

Comment: Oh BTW -(and because you seem new here), if an answer solved the problem for you, you can mark it as "accepted" by hovering over it - and a tick-mark should appear on the left... then you click that and it is accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Taryn - "accepted" your answer :d .... NisseEngstrom - I'm new to all this stuff - I don't know what a parser is. I'm just taking it one line/one file at a time...barraging Google with questions and when that doesn't work I come here. :D

Answer (score 5):

Your file is named `index.html`. Unless you told your server that .html files should be treated as PHP scripts, that means the PHP code is **NOT** being executed - it's going out as literal text. And since PHP tags make it look like HTML, your browser is properly hiding that unknown/illegal tag.

Rename it to `index.php`.

Comment: OP could learn to spot this by hitting "view source" rather than just gazing at the rendered output.

Answer (score 1):

Web servers are usually configured to run PHP only on files with the `.php` extension. Your `index.html` file will be passed as-is to the browser, which will probably ignore the unknown PHP tags. If you take a look at the source code of the web page, the tags will probably be there.

---

If you must have a `.html` extension, you can usually configure the web server to run PHP on `.html` files. For example, in Apache, you can use the [`AddType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) directive in an [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#htaccess) file or in the server configuration ([`httpd.conf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#main)):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

However, this will run PHP on *all* `.html` files (in that directory), which may put an unnecessary load on the server.

---

A much better way is to use URLs *without* extensions. In Apache, you can use the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive to specify a list of index files that the web server will search for:

```
Options +Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

When a browser requests a URL that ends with a slash, such as `http://mydomain.example/foo/`, the server will search for `foo/index.html` or `foo/index.php` in the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) (or, failing both, generate a directory listing). You can now use whichever type of index file is appropriate for the moment, without ever having to change your URLs.